# Unable to upload image using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to upload image using retrofit 2.0.

**1.APIServiceInterface.java**

```
    public interface APIServiceInterface {

    @POST("almabay_oauth/authorize")
    Call<ResponseLogin> login(@Body UserLogin userLogin); // Sending JSON object in login method and response will be stoed in POJO ResponseLogin

    // /webservice/media?user_id=<user_id>&type=photo&active=1&access_token=<access_token>
    //Uploading Image to server
    @Multipart
    @POST("webservice/media/")
    Call<ResponseUploadImage> uploadImage(@Query("user_id") String userID,
                                          @Query("type") String type,
                                          @Query("active") Long active,
                                          @Query("access_token") String accessToken,
                                          @Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file
    );
}
```

**2.ServiceGenerator.java**

```
    public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://phpstack-11819-25991-62288.cloudwaysapps.com/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


}
```

But here i am getting error while using OkHttpClient. Builder which says that can not resolve Builder class.

**3. build.gradle file:**

```
   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
}
```

Please guide me how can I upload file to server using Retrofit 2.0.

I am using [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) tutorial to upload file to server. Here I need to create a Service Generator class as given below:

I have edited my code now.
Please don't consider the above mentioned code. Consider the following now:
**Edited Code:**

**1.build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

**2.ServiceGenerator.java**

```
    public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://phpstack-11819-25991-62288.cloudwaysapps.com/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**3.WelcomeActivity.java**

```
 APIServiceInterface service =
                    ServiceGenerator.createService(APIServiceInterface.class);

            String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
            RequestBody description =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

            File file = new File(path);
            RequestBody requestBody =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            String type = "photo";
            int active = 1;
            Call<ResponseUploadImage> call = service.uploadImage(userID, type, active, accessToken, requestBody, description);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseUploadImage>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<ResponseUploadImage> response) {
                    Log.e("Status Code", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        ResponseUploadImage responseUploadImage = response.body();
                        String statusCode = responseUploadImage.getStatusCode();
                        Log.e("StatusCode", statusCode);
                        Detail detail = responseUploadImage.getDetail();
                        UploadData uploadData = detail.getUploadData();
                        String fileName = uploadData.getFileName();
                        Log.e("FileName",fileName);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Response", "failure");
                    Log.e("StackTrace", String.valueOf(t));

                }
```

**Expected JSON Response:**

```
 {
    "detail": {
        "upload_data": {
            "file_name": "AlmaBay_Homepage_Screenshot.png",
            "file_type": "image\/png",
            "file_path": "\/var\/www\/html\/ecampusbay\/common\/marvel\/photos\/2015\/10\/20\/",
            "full_path": "\/var\/www\/html\/ecampusbay\/common\/marvel\/photos\/2015\/10\/20\/AlmaBay_Homepage_Screenshot.png",
            "raw_name": "AlmaBay_Homepage_Screenshot",
            "orig_name": "AlmaBay_Homepage_Screenshot.png",
            "client_name": "AlmaBay Homepage Screenshot.png",
            "file_ext": ".png",
            "file_size": 5073.14,
            "is_image": true,
            "image_width": 1919,
            "image_height": 899,
            "image_type": "png",
            "image_size_str": "width=\"1919\" height=\"899\""
        }
    },
    "statusCode": "200"
}
```

While parsing the JSON response, I am getting the status code of 200 which is specified in the Response String. But I am not able to receive file_name from the upload_data object. I am not able to know where I am doing the mistake. Please help me to fix the problem.

**URL to be used is :**

```
 http://phpstack-11819-25991-62288.cloudwaysapps.com/webservice/media/?user_id=<user_id>&type=photo&active=1&access_token=<access_token>
```

Image need to be uploaded as multipart/form-data. 
File ‘name’ attribute must be ‘image’.

Comment: I think you required `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'`

Comment: it is not working for me .

Comment: If your issue has not been solved, please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491096/retrofit-multipart-request-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-pre?lq=1 to see if it can help or not