# Correct Way to Post Binary Data Using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have recently moved from using Retrofit 1.9 to Retrofit 2, and am experiencing a problem in posting binary data.

When I was using Retrofit 1.9, I was able to send a `TypedByteArray` that contained `byte[]` data as the `@Body` of a request. The closest equivalent to `TypedByteArray` seems to be `RequestBody`, which I am using as follows:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 5, byteOutputStream);
final byte[] thumbnailBytes = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
final RequestBody thumbnailRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), thumbnailBytes);
```

The code to generate the request is below:

```
Headers("Content-Type: image/jpeg")
@POST("/thumbnail")
Call<Void> uploadThumbnail(@Body RequestBody thumbnailContent);
```

However, it seems that Retrofit may be trying to parse the `RequestBody` as a JSON object, since the data that actually gets sent to the server is `{}`.

Any advice or guidance on how to correctly post binary data would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: instead of using `@RequestBody`, use `@Part`

Comment: You can use `Call<ResponseBody> postFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("description") RequestBody description);`. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491096/retrofit-multipart-request-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-pre/36514662#36514662

Answer (score 1):

Create your request like this

```
Headers("Content-Type: image/jpeg")
@POST("/thumbnail")
@Multipart
Call<Void> uploadThumbnail(@Part RequestBody thumbnailContent);
```

Call it like this

```
File partFile = <your_stream_as_file>;
RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image"), partFile);
uploadThumbnail(fbody);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `RequestBody` still seems to send `{}` to the server.

Comment: The error has now been fixed by @sapht, but in the future: if your answer needs a correction, click the question's "edit" link and fix it. The comments are a place to say "Oops, needed to change X to Y, that's done now", not "Would someone please change X to Y?"