# How to read @Multipart parameters using retrofit 2 in PHP?

Tags: php, retrofit

I'm trying to upload an image using retrofit 2 to a PHP server, but I don't know how can I reach this/these parameters in PHP.

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload/TestImage")
Call<ResultObj> getImageOne(@Part("file\";file=\"image.png\"") RequestBody file);

@Multipart
@POST("upload/TestImage")
Call<ResultObj> uploadImage(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the retrofit version: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1' and using the multipart in this way:

```java
@Multipart
@POST("/example/UpdInfo")
Call<Result> UpdateInfo(@Part MultipartBody.Part pic, @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

Comment: More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491096/retrofit-multipart-request-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-pre/36514662